# Random variables with equal CDF

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I've stuck with the following problem. If we have two random variables with equal CDFs (cumultive distribution functions), should they be equal everywhere except at a set of measure zero?

It seems they should at least for descrete variables with finite domain as well as for continuous variables with smooth density. But are there more complicated examples, for which the answer is another?

Comment: Are you sure you mean to ask if the two random variables must be equal?  If you do, then when you say "except at a set of measure zero", a set of *what* of measure zero?  Joint probability space?  That seems to me to be obviously false, hence the question of what you really want to know.

Comment: @BrianTung, to be precise, I want to know does this $P(X \ne Y) = 0$ hold every time, when X and Y have the same CDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unless the random variables are constant this doesn't need to be true. The distribution of a random variable bears very little information about the underlying probability space on which the random variable is defined. The random variables don't even need to be defined on the same probability space in order to have the same CDF.

So see an example, assume that $X$ and $Y$ are nonconstant independent random variables that have the same CDF and satisfy $P(X = Y) = 1$. Since they are not constant, there is a set $A$ so that $P(X \in A) \notin \{0, 1\}$. But this contradicts the independence of $X$ and $Y$, since it would imply
$$P(X \in A) = P(X \in A, Y \in A) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in A) = P(X\in A)^2.$$
[note that the equation $x = x^2$ has the only solutions $x = 0$ and $x = 1$].

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you explain please in two more words how did you get this $P(X \in A) = P(X \in A, Y \in A)$ ?

Comment: That's because $X = Y$ almost surely, which implies $X \in A \iff Y \in A$ almost surely. So see a more formal proof, use the rule $P(K) = P(K \cap L) + P(K \cap L^c)$ twice, where the set $L$ is $\{Y \in A\}$ resp. $\{X = Y\}$.

Comment: ooooh, sorry, it seems that I've not understood the problem right, while you got it:) thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Even if $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same probability space, they need not be equal almost everywhere if they have the same distribution. For example, on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure define $X(\omega)=\omega$, $Y(\omega)=1-\omega$. Then both $X$ and $Y$ have uniform$[0,1]$ distribution, but $P(X=Y)=0$, since the only place where $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ is $\omega=1/2$.